# Homotopy operator for the Gysin sequnce

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let's consider some sphere bundle $π:E ↦ M$ with fiber $S^{r}$.
What is homotopy operators in case of the Gysin sequence?
$$
\ldots \rightarrow H_{dR}^p(B) \xrightarrow{\wedge e} H_{dR}^{p+r+1}(B) \xrightarrow{\pi^{*}} H_{dR}^{p+r-1}(E) \xrightarrow{i} H_{dR}^{p+1}(B) \rightarrow \ldots,
$$
where $e$ is the Euler class, $i$ is a "integration along the fiber".

Comment: What does "homotopy operator" mean?

Comment: There exist an operator $K: \text{Ker}\ \pi^{*} \rightarrow H_{dR}^{p}(B)$ such that $$K(\omega) \wedge e = \omega$$ in the sense of the cohomology. I want to understand why this sequences is exact.